# Assign object properties to list in a set order

Tags: python

How can I iterate over an object and assign all it properties to a list

From

```
a = []

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myinstatt1 = 'one'
        self.myinstatt2 = 'two'
```

to

```
a =['one','two']
```

Comment: `vars(x).values()`, but why?

Comment: I want to store values in an object but  they are only usable on API as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a full fledged class if you just want to store a bunch of attributes and return a list so that your API can consume it. Use a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead. Here is an example.

```
>>> import collections
>>> Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(1, 2)
>>> p
Point(x=1, y=2)
```

If your API just expects a sequence (not specifically a `list`), you can pass `p` directly. If it needs a list specifically, it is trivial to convert the `Point` object to a list.

```
>>> list(p)
[1, 2]
```

You can even subclass the newly created `Point` class and add more methods (documentation has details). If `namedtuple` doesn't meet your needs, consider sub-classing [`abc.Sequence`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Sequence) Abstract Base Class or using it as a mixin.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make your class behave like a `list` by implementing some or all of the [container API](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types). Depending on how the external API you're using works, you might only need to implement `__iter__`. If it needs more, you could always pass it `list(a)`, which will build a list using an iterator.

Here's an example of how easy it can be to add an `__iter__` method:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myAttr1 = "one"
        self.myAttr2 = "two"

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.myAttr1
        yield self.myAttr2
```